# What to do when the OP accepts the wrong answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, not-an-answer, self-answer

I found some questions about it, but not sure if it applies to this case. The OP makes a question and someone answered it, very informative, but wrongly. I also made an answer (more like a guess) and I was wrong, too.

After some time, the OP found the real answer of his problem, posted it but didn't accept it. Seeing that, I asked them to accept their answer, but the OP ended up accepting the first answer (probably because it has upvotes).

Should I ask the OP (again) to accept their own answer? Can I edit the accepted answer adding the OP information, so it will be a complete answer?

I'm not sure if it's polite to ask the OP to remove the check mark from someone else's answer, but, at same time, the answer does not have the solution of the initial problem. What are my options here?

Comment: I guess it depends on how wrong is the first answer. It could not solve the problem entirely but almost, or could be completely wrong.

Comment: What's the use of accepted answers anyways? Search for issues regarding git version control. Most accepted answers relate to outdated versions or explicitly mention a version 1.7 that was released 6 years or so ago.

Comment: @Oriol I see, but there was nothing "wrong" about the first answer. All it said was right, but was basically the same thing the OP said wasn't working for him. But nevermind, the OP already accepted his own answer. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

They might not be aware that they're allowed to accept their own answer, so I don't see anything wrong with a comment letting them know. This way you don't have to explicitly tell them to unaccept the other answer. Something along the lines of "Just FYI, you are allowed to accept your own answer to your question, since it contains the correct answer."

Comment: Thank you, that's probably the case. I think i will do that. I hope you don't mind if i copy this sentence.

Comment: @Clyff You're welcome. I don't mind at all.

Comment: You can copy anything but you need to link the license :p

Comment: It may not be relevant in this particular case but when I suggest to an OP that they should convert their SOLVED comment to an answer, I always mention the [48 waiting period](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I also feel that my "self answers" were not as generously welcomed as the non-self ones by the community. Probably many are unaware of this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 24):

You can post a comment in the wrong answers indicating the problem for future readers in the case that the OP don't accept the correct answer. And you can post a comment too in the OP answer. If the situation changes, you can delete your comments.